# How to design an android activity in order to view recent posts with the support of "see more" property like facebook?

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application in order to facilitate the communication between students in some college through sharing posts and subjects written by them, so my idea is to create an activity showing recent posts.
i think that i need listview widget to show posts in a way such that each item in this listview will show one post with its title. is that correct? please, i want just the names of widgets which may used in such activity, and how to support "see more" for each post like facebook?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For see more you can use Floating action button. If new posts are available and the use scrolls down then the floating action button become visible.